# Querying a database in Flask

Tags: python, database, flask

I'm getting `AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'check_password`' when I attempt to call `check_password` on the User object I create in `forms.py` below. Here are the two lines where the problem occurs:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(userID = self.userID.data) 
if user and user.check_password(self.password.data):
   ...
```

The relevant source code is below. I know the `check_password()` method works because I can call it from within `models.py`. I'm not sure why I have access to the User model but not the `check_password` function.

forms.py

```
...    
from .models import User

    class LoginForm(Form):
       ...

        def validate(self):
            if not Form.validate(self):
              return False

            ***user = User.query.filter_by(userID = self.userID.data)***     
            ***if user and user.check_password(self.password.data)***:
              return True
            else:
              self.userID.errors.append("Invalid user ID or password")
              return False
```

models.py

```
from app import db
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        social_id = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False) #could have duplicate
        userID = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
        email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
        pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(54), nullable=True)  
        posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

        def __init__(self, social_id, userID, email, password):
            if social_id:
                self.social_id = social_id #not required if not using Facebook login
            if userID:
                self.userID = userID
            self.email = email.lower()
            if password:
                self.set_password(password)
                assert self.check_password(password)

        def set_password(self, password):
            self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

        def check_password(self, password):
            return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User.query.filter_by()` will return the query. If you want the first result of the query you need to call `first()`, i.e.

```
User.query.filter_by(...).first()
```